# must implement method doInBackground (params)

Tags: android

I have a class extending AsyncTask which has to implement doInBackground method.
I have the method defined below , still I have an error saying the class has to implement method.

```
public class MyDownloadJsonAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<Void , String, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<RecyclerView_Adapter> adapterReference;
MovieDataJson movieData;

public MyDownloadJsonAsyncTask(RecyclerView_Adapter adapter)
{
    adapterReference = new WeakReference<RecyclerView_Adapter>(adapter);
}


@Override
protected MovieDataJson doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    MovieDataJson threadMovieData = new MovieDataJson();
    for (String url : urls)
    {
        threadMovieData.downloadMovieDataJson(url);
    }
    return threadMovieData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(MovieDataJson threadMovieData)
{

    movieData.moviesList.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<threadMovieData.getSize();i++)
    {
        movieData.moviesList.add(threadMovieData.moviesList.get(i));
    }
    if(adapterReference!=null)
    {
        final RecyclerView_Adapter adapter= adapterReference.get();
        if(adapter!=null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

and at @Override for each method above says method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: Check your generic types!

Comment: change your firsr parameter of AsyncTask as string.public class MyDownloadJsonAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Bitmap>

Comment: I changed the parameters to <String,Void,MovieDataJson>
Thanks a lot!